# Colossal memory usage/stack problems with ANTLR lexer/parser

Tags: memory-management, antlr, antlr4

I'm porting over a grammar from flex/bison, and mostly seem to have everything up and running (in particular, my token stream seems fine, and my parser grammar is compiling and running), but seem to be running into problems of runaway stack/memory usage even with very small/moderate sized inputs to my grammar. What is the preferred construct for chaining together an unbounded sequence of the same nonterminal? In my Bison grammar I had production rules of the form:

```
statements: statement | statement statements
words: | word words
```

In ANTLR, if I maintain the same rule setup, this seems to perform admirably on small inputs (on the order of 4kB), but leads to stack overflow on larger inputs (on the order of 100kB). In both cases the automated parse tree produced is also rather ungainly.

I experimented with changing these production rules to have an explicitly additive (rather than recursive form):

```
statements: statement+
words: word*
```

However this seems to have lead to absolutely horrific blowup in memory usage (upwards of 1GB) on even very small inputs, and the parser has not yet managed to return a parse tree after 20 minutes of letting it run.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've gotten it working, in the following manner. My YACC grammar had the following constructions:

```
lines: lines | line lines;
words: | word words;
```

However, this did not make the recursive parsing happy, so I rewrote it as:

```
lines: line+;
words: word*;
```

Which is in line with @280Z28's feedback (and my original guess). This hung the parser, which is why I posted the question in the first place, but the debugging procedure outlined in my comments to @280Z28's answer showed that in fact it was only the `lines` parsing which was causing the problem (`words`) was fine. On a whim, I tried the following rewrite:

```
lines   : stmt (EOL stmt)+ EOL*;
```

(where `line` had originally been defined as:

```
line : stmt (EOL | EOF);
```

)

This seems to be working quite well, even for large inputs. However it is entirely unclear to me WHY this is the Right Thing To Do(tm), or why it makes a difference compared to the revision which prompted this question. Any feedback on this matter would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your rewritten statements are the optimal ANTLR 4 form of the two rules you described (highest performing and minimum memory usage). Here is some general feedback regarding the issues you describe.

1. I developed some very advanced diagnostic code for numerous potential performance problems. Much of this code is included in [`TestPerformance`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/TestPerformance.java), but it is geared towards expert users and requires a rather deep understanding of ANTLR 4's new ALL(*) algorithm to interpret the results.
2. Terence and I are interested in turning the above into a tool that users can make use of. I may be able to help (run and interpret the test) if you provide a complete grammar and example inputs, so that I can use that grammar and input pair as part of evaluating the usability of a tool further down the road that automates the analysis.
3. Make sure you are using the two-stage parsing strategy from the book. In many cases, this will vastly improve the parsing performance for correct inputs (incorrect inputs would not be faster).
4. We don't like to use more memory than necessary, but you should be aware that we are working under a very different definition of "excessive" - e.g. we run our testing applications with `-Xmx4g` to `-Xmx12g`, depending on the test.

Comment: I am using separate lexer + parser stages (and have `options {tokenVocab = ...}` configured appropriately. I have experience with lexing/parsing in general, but am new to ANTLR and know very little about ALL(*) specifically, so any interpretational help you can provide would be wonderful.

[edit -- oops, hit enter before I meant to, forgot Stack Overflow does that. wait for the rest of the post :) ]

Comment: follow-up comment:

I don't mind large memory usage in general (my laptop has 8GB...), but I define "excessive" relative to the task at hand (for example a 2kb file probably shouldn't take 1GB+ to parse). 

My grammars and several sample inputs of varying size are here: [link](http://cs.brown.edu/~tdickerson/ParseTest.zip)

Comment: Okay, so I don't know if you've had time to look at this yet, but here are some updated findings:
`java -cp .:../antlr4-complete4257927153464703627.jar org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig LDraw ldrawLine -tokens -tree ~/LDRAW/MODELS/small_blaster.ldr` correctly and quickly parses the first line of the file.
`cat ~/LDRAW/MODELS/small_blaster.ldr | xargs -L 1 -I{} sh -c 'echo {} | java -cp .:../antlr4-complete4257927153464703627.jar org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig LDraw ldrawLine -tokens -tree'` correctly and quickly parses each line of the file separately.

Comment: but parsing even a single line with ldrawLines works not at all (nor does trying to parse the entire file in the same manner). Definitions are in the file linked above, but for convenience:
`ldrawLine : ldrawStmt (EOL | EOF)` and
`ldrawLines: ldrawLine+`.